# Compiling CPU Multi Miner on OS X

Tags: cpu-mining, compile, macos

I've been trying to compile CPU Multiminer on OS X: https://github.com/wolf9466/cpuminer-multi

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Would be grateful if there was some instructions, I just can't get it to build!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[goxed from bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=632724.msg9073412#msg9073412)  has a fork of that repo that fixed the clang issues and works for me on macOS10.12. Here's what I did to use it without the formula:

```
brew install automake autoconf libtool curl jansson
brew link curl --force
git clone git://github.com/goxed/cpuminer-multi;cd cpuminer-multi
./autogen.sh
perl ./nomacro.pl
./configure CFLAGS="-march=native -mtune=native -maes"
make
```

Edit: since the wolf9466 repo has seen a few changes since the goxed version was forked, I just tried making the same Makefile.am changes that goxed did to the current wolf9466 repo, and that also works.

Answer (score 0):

for modern MacOs Versions you'll need to install openssl and pass it as parameter in configure

```
brew install openssl
./configure CFLAGS="-march=native -mtune=native -maes -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
```

and apply this patch:
https://github.com/ivoputzer/cpuminer-multi/commit/c8d38bc86519e20d36dc3d0bd1e07b64d8ab73ae